# scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d is there a quicker pythonic way to know which bin each rows unique_id went into?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I have a dataframe that has Latitude, Longitude, and a unique_id for each row.

```
df = df[['unique_id','Latitude','Longitude']]
```

I am using `stats.binned_statistic_2d` to create bins that lat/long will correspond with.

```
stats, yedges, xedges, binnumbers = stats.binned_statistic_2d(
    np.array(df['Latitude']),
    np.array(
        df['Longitude']),
        bins=bins,
        values=np.array(df['unique_id']),
        statistic = 'count'
    )
)
```

But after applying this, I would like to produce another column in the dataframe that shows which bin number the `unique_id` is in, where `df` will now have `df[['unique_id','Latitude','Longitude','binnumber']]`.

Is there an easy pythonic way to do this rather than nesting loops across `xedges` and `yedges`?

I already tried nesting loops, but that is way too slow and I am sure there is an easier pythonic way to do this.

TIA!

Comment: `binnumbers` is already what you are looking for, isn't it?

From the docs of [scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html): `binnumber`: "This assigns to each element of sample an integer that represents the bin in which this observation falls. The representation depends on the expand_binnumbers argument. See Notes for details."

I think you have to parse `np.array(df['unique_id'])` to the `values` argument of `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d`. Then, you just have to append `binnumbers` to your data frame.

Comment: @andthum ok, so the values that are returned in binnumbers are already in the order of the original df? therefore all I have to do is add that list as a new column in the original df. If so, that is what I was looking for. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Yes, I think so. But you should check if the result from `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d` is the same as your nested loop approach.